# DIP switches not working properly

Tags: switches, dip, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying a project involving a DIP switch and a Raspberry Pi Pico, but it isn't working correctly.

When I switch all the switches to off on the DIP switch and test to see if any are still connected, switches 7, 6, 5, and 4 are still considered on. I looked around to see if there was a loose wire somewhere that was connecting the two ends, but nothing came up.

If it ends up having something to do with the internals of the switch, is there a way of opening up the switch and fixing it myself? Though it would be best if it's fixed without having to do that.

I attached some images (sorry in advance, the soldering is shoddy).

*Bottom view of DIP switches*
[image: Bottom view of DIP switches]

*Angled view of Pico Board with soldering*
[image: Angled view of Pico Board with soldering]

*Top-down view of DIP switches*
[image: Top-down view of DIP switches]

*Top-down view of Pico board*
[image: Top-down view of Pico board]

Comment: My guess is that your heavy-handed soldering has partially melted the case of the dip switch, and some of the contacts have shifted to a permanently-closed position as a result. Next time, solder the switch to a piece of proto board, and then do the wiring from there.

Comment: Does the switch have pull-ups? What value? The internal pull-ups are fairly weak and there might be conductive residue from soldering. Cleaning it with alcohol and soap and water might help. You could try external pull-ups of about 1k.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the suggestion. I will desolder the DIP Switch and try again but with a proto board to protect it.

Comment: @PStechPaul What is a pull-up? (Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm very new to this stuff)

Comment: A pull-up is a resistor that provides a voltage on an input that is near the power supply (Vdd) rail, for a logic high. The switch or other signal will then drive it to GND for a logic low.

Comment: To be clear, you should use a fresh dip switch. I doubt you can repair that one.